# Bizarre application of the mean value theorem

Tags: integration, analysis, fourier-analysis, exponential-function

In a book I am reading, if $|\xi|\le|x-y|^{-1}$, then the mean value theorem is used to estimate

$$|e^{-ix\cdot\xi}-e^{-iy\cdot\xi}|^{2}\le c|x\cdot\xi-y\cdot\xi|^{2}.$$

I am familiar with the mean value theorem for integrals and where we have an expression in the form of a quotient, but I don't see how it has been employed here.

I am solving an exercise in which I have a similar problem. That is, $|\xi|\le|y|^{-1}$ and I want to estimate

$$|e^{-i(x+2y)\cdot\xi}-2e^{-i(x+y)\cdot\xi}+e^{-ix\cdot\xi}|^{2}.$$

Comment: Are the quantities $x \cdot \xi$ , $ y \cdot \xi $ real?

Comment: @copper.hat Yes, $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^{2}$ and $\xi$ is the frequency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I have assumed that $ x \cdot \xi ,y \cdot \xi$ are real here.)

Let $f(t) = e^{it}$, then $|f'(t)| = 1$ for all $t$ and so
$|f(s)-(t)| \le |s-t|$ for all $s,t$.

In the above, $s=x \cdot \xi $, $t = y \cdot \xi$, hence
$|e^{i x \cdot \xi} - e^{y \cdot \xi} | \le | x \cdot \xi - y \cdot \xi |$.

Addendum:

Since $f(s) -f(t)= \int_0^1 f'(t+\tau(s-t)) d \tau (s-t)$, we have
$|f(s) -f(t)| \le  \int_0^1 |f'(t+\tau(s-t))| d \tau |s-t| \le |s-t| $.

Comment: Are you claiming that $|f(s)-f(t)|=|f'(u)||s-t|$ for some $u$ for this complex function $f$?

Comment: @TrialAndError: No. There is an inequality above, not equality. The inequality follows from $f(y)-f(x)=\int_0^1 f'(x+t(y-x))dt (y-x)$.

Comment: You left out that critical bit of information, and it could lead to the false conclusion that the mean value theorem somehow applies to complex functions, which was the concern of the OP.

Comment: @TrialAndError: The OP mentioned the mean value theorem for integrals and I assumed that meant the above; I will add a clarification.

Answer (score 2):

You know that $f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ with $f(z) = e^z$ is an entire function with $f'(z) = e^z$. Thus, for any $u, v \in \mathbb{C}$ we have
$$  \int_{u}^v e^z dz = e^v - e^u$$
and the absolute value of $e^z$ on the segment $[u, v]$ is bounded by $c_{u,v} = e^{\max(\text{Re} u,\text{Re} v)}$. We conclude that
$$|e^v - e^u| \le   c |u - v|.$$
Notice you can take $c$ as a constant independent of $u$ and $v$ if the numbers you are considering are bounded.